# Superuser: You won 'Necromancer'?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

[A few of us on Super User have won Necromancer.](https://superuser.com/badges/17/necromancer) Judging by the number of days SU has been opened, and the days required to qualify a question for Necromancer, I wouldn't think this was possible.

Comment: Given the number of answers you've provided there already, I'd be surprised if one of them wasn't somehow very old :)

Comment: I've got to if I plan on sharing column 1 with the greats for very long :)

Comment: can't think of any way to fix this short of disabling the badge on meta

Comment: What about resetting the timestamp on migrated questions?

Comment: I have a Necromancer badge on Meta because I answered Jon Skeet Facts in January (or maybe February) and didn't collect my fifth vote until it had been moved here.

Comment: It's no longer page 1 that holds the greats, now you have to be in *column 1*? Man...

Answer (score 7):

Most likely a bug related to the migration of posts. This one, in your case:

> https://superuser.com/questions/4714/whats-your-favorite-harmless-computer-practical-joke

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug as the questions that were migrated were indeed over 60 days old

Comment: Bug or undocumented feature, I don't think it was intended ;)

Comment: I consider it a bug because I feel the badge should be rewarded with respect to the time it was migrated over, since it has only existed on *that* particular site for that amount of time.

Comment: Agreed, I think that questions closed elsewhere (like SF) would still age in the background.  Besides, if you use the more generic definition of necromancer (e.g., sorcerer), you have performed a bit o' magic by answering a question more than 60 days old on a site that's not 10 days old!